# Is it possible to maintain a reusable django *project* across apps?

Tags: python, django, git

I'm trying to decide whether underneath 'reusable apps' it is doable to maintain a reusable bare project setup as well.

On a side note: I can destroy any of my servers and rebuild it in barely hours as long as I have a (data) backup and a blueprint (in my case saltstack, but it might just as well be puppet, chef or what not).

With a flexible infra, these deployment steps are next:

- Create  a virtualenv for the django application
- Check out my project (always named project)
- My project has a setup.py included. This sets the surroundings:

  - render settings files based on yaml data and templates
  - Possibly loads fixtures when needed
  - When in production, it renders apache config
  - etc
- After that, as git submodules, you can plug your reusable apps to end up with a running webapplication.

With quite a lot of intelligency built in the bare project base structure I ended up with my original question.

I'm wondering if the project baseline is maintainable as a cross (Web)Application seperate git repo. Or does the project structure itself have to much specific moving parts related to the (Web)Application as a whole?

E.g: pluggable apps go in INSTALLED_APPS, etc and always ending up with to much related/changing data.

Hope it's clear. Looking forward to you comments

Comment: It's quite common and fully supported, actually: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/project-templates/

Comment: You could probably use `cookiecutter` to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanx for the pointers! :) ... When rendering a project based on a template, that is the point where a project 'forks' (is born) into it's own entity. Therewith ...  Can repeating myself (copy/paste or otherwise) be avoided when a project is generated based on a newer template, when I want to update previously published live projects as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility, as suggested, is templating the project which could suffice. However, templating projects would result in a different starting point for every project. Since templates evolve over time there's not one project that starts the same.

Having a baseline throughout all your projects seems only worth pursuing if your big enough as a (development) company and are building enough different projects. A baseline in this case can be a custom python egg or additional django app added to your Django project. Such an app can enforce deployment strategies or help maintain infrastructural dependancies.

For instance, propagating/configuring server information about your infrastructure or other services. Think of db, storage, auth services and other backends. When moving to a different inhouse storage backend or it's new API version, your app can smoothen the transition. If you don't already have added (re-usable) apps to your project specifically to hook up your project to the storage service.

So, in short, I think the answer to my own question is:

Yes, create reusable apps for this as far as possible but always make sure the solution is not bigger then the problem.